# makefile notdir command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

my source files are not inside of one directory which I need to do ../ or ../../ stuff.

after that, I need to change source file name  for example: `../ex/test.c to  obj/test.o`

with this: command:

```
$(OBJDIR) $(notdir $(SOURCECODE:.c=.o))
```

however only first filename in `$(SOURCECODE)` (`../ex/test.c`) is correctly renamed to obj/test.o, the rest all look like `*.o`, without directory information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you prepend `$(OBJDIR)` to the list as is: `obj/` + `foo.c bar.c baz.c` gives `obj/foo.c bar.c baz.c`, which is not what you want.

To add directory to each file in your list use [`addprefix`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) function:

```
$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(notdir $(SOURCECODE:.c=.o)))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(notdir $(SOURCECODE:.c=.o)))
```

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov: But you wrote the better explanation :-). +1.